# Different icons with OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm implementing github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier to make clusters of Pin's on my google map.

What I want to do is to have a i cluster icon with a number in it that tells the user how many pin's there are - Just like google default cluster view. Se screendump. If it's not possible to have a number, that is okay as long as i can set a cluster icon of my choice.
[image]
*Screen shows how clusters looks on **google***
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

When i click the cluster it opens up and show the pin's. In my case each pin is a small thumbnail. Se screendump
[image]
*Screen shows how it looks **after** i click the cluster*

My problem is that i dont know how to make something like the google cluster solution. My code show a thumbnail as the cluster icon (see screendumb) and i want the 'google solution'.
[image]
*Screen shows how it looks **before** i click the cluster*

-- My script so far --

```
// Some sample data
var mapData = [{lat:56.03519372,lng:12.61253154,picture:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/2764678/pexels-photo-2764678.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=200"},{lat:55.69293644,lng:12.56145395,picture:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/1779487/pexels-photo-1779487.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=200"},{lat:55.69293644,lng:12.56145395,picture:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/3184454/pexels-photo-3184454.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=200"},{lat:55.69293644,lng:12.56145395,picture:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/4144294/pexels-photo-4144294.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=200"},{lat:55.69293644,lng:12.56145395,picture:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/1714208/pexels-photo-1714208.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=200"}];


function initMap() {
  var clusterMarker = [];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng( mapLat, mapLng),
    zoom: 10,
  });

  // Create infowindow
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  // Create OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier instsance
  var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map,{
    markersWontMove: true, 
    markersWontHide: true,
  });

  // This is necessary to make the Spiderfy work
  oms.addListener('click', function(marker) {
    infoWindow.setContent(marker.desc);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  var iconSize = new google.maps.Size(50, 50);

  for (var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i ++) {
    var point = mapData[i];
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);

    // create marker at location
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });

    marker.setIcon({
      url: point.ad_picture,
      size: iconSize,
      scaledSize: iconSize  // makes SVG icons work in IE
    });

    // needed to make Spiderfy work
    oms.addMarker(marker);

    // needed to cluster marker
    clusterMarker.push(marker);
  }

  new MarkerClusterer(map, clusterMarker, {imagePath: 'images/m', maxZoom: 6});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is the clustering working as you want? What do you mean by `marker.setIcon({})` "changes the cluster icon"? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, preferably a functional  [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: It looks to me like you should have unique icons for each location (assuming your input data provides them).

Comment: Yes the script works as it should and creates cluster in the right places. When i click on a cluster all the markes also has the right image. I'm using this to set images for each marker.
    `marker.setIcon({
      url: point.ad_picture,
      size: iconSize,
      scaledSize: iconSize
    });`

Problem is that the Cluster icon (before it's clicked) gets the first images from a normal marker. Instead i want a marker like google has where you can see how many markers that a joined together. (Ex. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering)

Comment: Your explanation of the problem still doesn't make sense to me (I don't know what this means:"the Cluster icon (before it's clicked) gets the first images from a normal marker.", what do you mean by a "normal" marker?). It would be helpful if you could provide a [mcve] that demonstrates that behavior, preferably a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in your question.

Comment: Okay i will see if i can make a better explanation :) I will return soon, thx. Can also mention that this is what i'm implementing https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

Comment: @geocodezip I have updated the description and added pictures, hope that makes it more clear :) It wasn't possible to make a StackSnippet.

Comment: Please provide some sample data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot that. Question is updated :)

Comment: With the provided data/code I get a javascript error: `InvalidValueError: setIcon: not a string; and not an instance of PinView; and no url property; and no path property` and default icons, not the images that appear in the pictures in your question.  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9jztfhok/)

Comment: looks like the samle data has 'picture:' and the script uses 'ad_picture'. Just type 'picture' in the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that will give you what I think you want would be to set the icon for "unspiderfied" markers to the cluster icon (the default is: `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m1.png`) and set that icons label to the number of markers spiderfied there.  Note that this won't have the full cluster behavior, it will always have the same icon (in this case the blue one), it won't change based on the number of markers at the same location.  If you want that to happen, you can implement that behavior, but that will be more complicated code.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() { 
    // can't call markersNearMarker until idle event fires
    oms.addListener('format', function(marker, status) {
      var iconURL = status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIED ? marker.uniqIcon :
        status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIABLE ? "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m1.png" :
        status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.UNSPIDERFIABLE ? marker.uniqIcon :
        null;
      var spiderfiedMarkers = oms.markersNearMarker(marker, false);
      marker.setIcon({
        url: iconURL,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
      });
      if (status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIABLE)
        marker.setLabel("" + (spiderfiedMarkers.length + 1));
      else
        marker.setLabel("");
    });
  });
```

Note added the unique icon for the marker as a property of the marker (`uniqIcon`), that is so the marker can be set to its unique icon once it is spiderfied:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location,
  map: map,
  uniqIcon: point.picture
});
marker.setIcon({
  url: point.picture,
  title: "" + i,
  size: iconSize,
  scaledSize: iconSize
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9jztfhok/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// Some sample data
var mapData = [{lat:56.03519372,lng:12.61253154,picture:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/2764678/pexels-photo-2764678.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=200"},{lat:55.69293644,lng:12.56145395,picture:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/1779487/pexels-photo-1779487.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=200"},{lat:55.69293644,lng:12.56145395,picture:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/3184454/pexels-photo-3184454.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=200"},{lat:55.69293644,lng:12.56145395,picture:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/4144294/pexels-photo-4144294.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=200"},{lat:55.69293644,lng:12.56145395,picture:"https://images.pexels.com/photos/1714208/pexels-photo-1714208.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=200"}];

var mapLat = 0;
var mapLng = 0;

function initMap() {
  var clusterMarker = [];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapLat, mapLng),
    zoom: 10,
  });

  // Create infowindow
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  // Create OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier instsance
  var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, {
    markersWontMove: true,
    markersWontHide: true,
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    oms.addListener('format', function(marker, status) {
      var iconURL = status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIED ? marker.uniqIcon :
        status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIABLE ? "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m1.png" :
        status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.UNSPIDERFIABLE ? marker.uniqIcon :
        null;
      var spiderfiedMarkers = oms.markersNearMarker(marker, false);
      marker.setIcon({
        url: iconURL,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50) // makes SVG icons work in IE
      });
      if (status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIABLE)
        marker.setLabel("" + (spiderfiedMarkers.length + 1));
      else
        marker.setLabel("");
    });
  });
  // This is necessary to make the Spiderfy work
  oms.addListener('click', function(marker) {
    infoWindow.setContent(marker.getTitle());
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  var iconSize = new google.maps.Size(50, 50);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++) {
    var point = mapData[i];
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);
    bounds.extend(location);
    // create marker at location
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
      uniqIcon: point.picture
    });
    marker.setIcon({
      url: point.picture,
      title: "" + i,
      size: iconSize,
      scaledSize: iconSize // makes SVG icons work in IE
    });

    // needed to make Spiderfy work
    oms.addMarker(marker);

    // needed to cluster marker
    clusterMarker.push(marker);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  new MarkerClusterer(map, clusterMarker, {
    imagePath: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m",
    maxZoom: 14
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map,
#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/bin/oms.min.js"></script>
```